# High poly meshes causing save time slow down

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, workflow

I've created a complex mesh for the scene I'm working on currently. The mesh consists of about 25k verts, and 12k faces. The mesh is used six times making the total project verts at around 140k, and 70k faces. When adding these meshes to the project file I noticed an immediate slow down in the time it takes for the project file to save to my hdd.

On its own this isn't too big of an issue, but the problem is I have a serious habit of frequently pressing Ctrl+S while working, as to avoid ever losing progress to a project should something happen. When saving takes increasingly longer times to do, it severely affects my workflow. In hopes to remedy this I added a remesh modifier that lowers the vert count significantly to only 52 verts per mesh in the viewport, but doesn't appear in the render, however despite this change it seems to not affect the save times whatsoever. Which means that though it is specifically as a result of the meshes being in the project file, its not inherently because of the vertices count. Or that blender is still processing the mesh as it was before the modifier was added to it.

Is there anything I can do to speed up my save times? Or will I have to sacrifice some verts in favor of a smoother workflow?

Thanks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these meshes 100% identical to one another?

Comment: Yes, however for the project they will be at different orientations and need to be animated independently.